# Postgresql - GROUP BY timestamp AND car_id

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got a table with car records:

```
table: cars

columns:
car_id | timestamp | km_driven
```

I'm running `PostgreSQL 9.6`.

How can I do a:

```
SELECT timestamp, car_id, km_driven_within_the_hour FROM cars
```

I want to `GROUP BY` my `timestamp` so all records recorded with each hour is grouped by each car, and then have `km_driven_within_the_hour` `SUM`'ed togehter within that hour.

I've tried:

```
SELECT timestamp, car_id, SUM(km_driven) AS km_driven_within_the_hour
FROM cars
GROUP BY trunc(EXTRACT(hour from timestamp)), car_id
```

Gives me error:

```
ERROR:  function pg_catalog.date_part(unknown, text) does not exist
```

And casting timestamp:

```
SELECT timestamp, car_id, SUM(km_driven) AS km_driven_within_the_hour
FROM cars
GROUP BY trunc(EXTRACT(hour from timestamp::timestamp)), car_id
```

Gives me:

```
ERROR:  column "cars.timestamp" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. Replace the `timestamp` by the hour, as in:

```
SELECT
    trunc(EXTRACT(hour from timestamp::timestamp)), 
    car_id, 
    SUM(km_driven) AS km_driven_within_the_hour
  FROM cars
  GROUP BY trunc(EXTRACT(hour from timestamp::timestamp)), car_id
```

Comment: Thank you. I would like, however, the timestamp to be `GROUP BY` the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH` and with this it only seems `hour` is shown, so I cannot differ between day, month and year.

Comment: Tried `group by date_trunc('hour', timestamp::timestamp)` but that results in multiple records/lines with same hour.

Comment: Seems `group by TO_CHAR(timestamp::timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH');` solves it.